# Как передать переменную между функциями

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, pyqt5, qlineedit

Получается ошибка, что переменная не определена, пробовал через `global`, но всё равно не получается.

**Как перевести переменную в другую функцию?** Нужно будет вывести диалоговое окно, поэтому и спрашиваю.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit, QToolTip, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout,
                             QMessageBox, QInputDialog)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QFont, QIcon, QFontDatabase)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.window()

    def window(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Body mass index")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("img/ico.png"))

        QToolTip.setFont(QFont("Josefin Slab", 15))

        self.okBtn = QPushButton("ok")
        self.okBtn.setToolTip("calculate")
        self.okBtn.setFont(QFont("Josefin Slab", 11))
#        self.okBtn.clicked.connect(self.calc())

        self.exitBtn = QPushButton("exit")
        self.exitBtn.setToolTip("close the program")
        self.exitBtn.setFont(QFont("Josefin Slab", 11))
        self.exitBtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        self.Hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Hbox.addStretch()
        self.Hbox.addWidget(self.okBtn)
        self.Hbox.addWidget(self.exitBtn)

        self.m = QLineEdit(self)
        self.m.setToolTip("Enter your weight here")

        self.h = QLineEdit(self)
        self.h.setToolTip("Enter your height here")

        self.Vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        self.Vbox.addWidget(self.m)
        self.Vbox.addWidget(self.h)

        self.Vbox.addLayout(self.Hbox)
        self.Vbox.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(self.Vbox)

        if self.h != "" and self.m != "":
            hq = self.h.text()
            mq = self.m.text()

            self.okBtn.clicked.connect(self.calc())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, "Exit", "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No,
                    QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
             event.ignore()

    def calc(self):
#       global hq
#       global mq
        self.bmi = float(mq) / (float(hq) * float(hq))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = QApplication(sys.argv)

    QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("fonts/josefin.ttf")

    start = App()
    start.setFixedSize(300, 100)
    start.show()

    sys.exit(root.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае, вам передавать ничего не надо. т.к. переменные, которые участвуют в расчетах являются атрибутами класса `App` (self.h , self.m), а следовательно доступны во всех методах данного класса. А если вам надо будет что-то передать, то вы можете воспользоваться функцией `lambda`

Попробуйте пример. Если вам, что-то будет не понятно - спросите, я отвечу.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit, 
                             QToolTip, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout,
                             QMessageBox, QInputDialog)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QFont, QIcon, QFontDatabase)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.window()

    def window(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Body mass index")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("img/ico.png"))

        QToolTip.setFont(QFont("Josefin Slab", 15))

        self.okBtn = QPushButton("ok")
        self.okBtn.setToolTip("calculate")
        self.okBtn.setFont(QFont("Josefin Slab", 11))
#        self.okBtn.clicked.connect(self.calc())
        self.okBtn.clicked.connect(self.calc)                            # +++

        self.exitBtn = QPushButton("exit")
        self.exitBtn.setToolTip("close the program")
        self.exitBtn.setFont(QFont("Josefin Slab", 11))
        self.exitBtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        self.Hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Hbox.addStretch()
        self.Hbox.addWidget(self.okBtn)
        self.Hbox.addWidget(self.exitBtn)

        self.m = QLineEdit(self)
        self.m.setToolTip("Enter your weight here")

        self.h = QLineEdit(self)
        self.h.setToolTip("Enter your height here")

        self.Vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        self.Vbox.addWidget(self.m)
        self.Vbox.addWidget(self.h)

        self.Vbox.addLayout(self.Hbox)
        self.Vbox.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(self.Vbox)

#        if self.h != "" and self.m != "":
#            hq = self.h.text()
#            mq = self.m.text()
#            self.okBtn.clicked.connect(self.calc())


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, "Exit", "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No,
                    QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
             event.ignore()

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def calc(self):
        hq = self.h.text()
        mq = self.m.text()    
        if not hq or not mq:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 
                    'Заполните пожалуйста все поля для рассчетов!')  
            return

#       global hq
#       global mq
        self.bmi = float(mq) / (float(hq) * float(hq))
        msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Резкльтат', 
                    f' {mq} / ({hq} * {hq}) = {self.bmi:.3f}')  
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("fonts/josefin.ttf")
    start = App()
    start.setFixedSize(300, 100)
    start.show()
    sys.exit(root.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо указать полный путь к переменной, например если в другом классе: `class.def.name`, где class - имя класса, def - имя функции и name - имя переменной. Либо же в том же классе, но из другой функции класса: `self.def.name`, где self - указывает что значение берётся из этого же класса, def - имя функции из которой берёте и nmae - имя переменной. Надеюсь помог)